# Git merge returns error code 128

Tags: git, return-code

I am doing null merge using below command  :

```
repo forall -pc "git merge --strategy=ours \${REPO_REMOTE}/parent_branch" >merge_merge.log 2>&1
```

This command always returns error code 128.

```
$ echo $?
128
```

Is it expected or i am missing something?? I checked log as well but there is no error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what happens when you just explicitly run the command?

Comment: same. it returns 128.

Comment: If i run git command without repo forall then it returns "0".

Comment: So I'm not thinking that the git command is the problem; something else in that command chain is.  I'd start with dissecting each call to see what's going on where.

Comment: this is the only command. :(

Comment: Is it because of parent_branch contains two slash "/" in its name?